# How to block specific URLs in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, url, block

I've been searching around the web for a way to block access to specific URL addresses in objective-c for OS X, but I've only come across the method of changing the hosts file. This is not a very good solution since my app needs to change the blocked websites regularly and the hosts-method requires an admin password every time the app changes the file.

So does anyone know a way to block specific URLs besides using the hosts file?

Thank you in advance, Rasmus.

Comment: What's the scope? Are you trying to block these URLs for the whole operating system, a specific user, or just your app?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NJones! I seek to prevent the user from opening certain domains (e.g. facebook.com or youtube.com) in their web browsers.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this question as well...

Comment: Make friends with your firewall admin.